# Line between point and cursor

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created a map in which the user can click-drag to make a free-form polyline as part of a polygon. However, I can't get it to where I can see the line extending from the point I just made to your cursor. I want to implement this functionality.

I am currently using click, mousemove, etc. event listeners for the free-form polyline, and these are disabled under the drawing library.

How is is exactly that Maps Engine Lite draws a line from the point you just clicked to the cursor when drawing a polygon or polyline?

I have already looked through the DrawingManager and DrawingOptions and can't figure out how it shows a line from point to the cursor programmatically.

I'm guessing I need to find the coordinates of my cursor on mousemove, and draw a line between that location and the last point I clicked. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it out:

```
   //observe click
    google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(e){
      //if there is no Polyline-instance, create a new Polyline
      //with a path set to the clicked latLng
       if(!line){
          line=new google.maps.Polyline({map:map,path:[e.latLng],clickable:false});
       }

       //always push the clicked latLng to the path
       //this point will be used temporarily for the mousemove-event 
       line.getPath().push(e.latLng);
       new google.maps.Marker({map:map,position:e.latLng,
                               draggable:true,
                               icon:{url:'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/dd-via.png',
                                     anchor:new google.maps.Point(5,5)}})

    });
    //observe mousemove
    google.maps.event.addListener(map,'mousemove',function(e){
      if(line){
      //set the last point of the path to the mousemove-latLng
        line.getPath().setAt(line.getPath().getLength()-1,e.latLng)
      }
    });
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/4yPDg/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/4yPDg/)

**Note:** this part of your code is redundant:

```
var coord = new google.maps.LatLng(option.latLng.lb, option.latLng.mb);
```

`option.latLng` is already a `google.maps.LatLng`, you may use  it directly

```
var coord = option.latLng;
```

**Furthermore:** you should never use these undocumented properties like `mb` or `lb` , the names of these properties are not fixed and may be changed in the next session.

Comment: I noticed that you did not nest the mousemove event inside the click. Are nested event listeners generally a bad idea?

Comment: I wouldn't say that(as long as you use them correctly and clear them when they are redundant)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a possible solution. It may not be the most elegant. Any other ideas?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(option) {
    var coord = new google.maps.LatLng(option.latLng.lb, option.latLng.mb);

    var connector = new google.maps.Polyline();

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function(pt) {
        connector.setMap(null);
        document.getElementById('latlgn').innerHTML = pt.latLng;

        var lineTwoPoints = [
            coord,
            pt.latLng
        ];
        connector.setPath(lineTwoPoints);
        connector.setMap(map);
    });
});
```